# How to pass column name to toscalar function?

Tags: kql

I have a kusto table with one of the columns as dynamic type with nested json.
If I use ColumnName in toscalar function, I will get this error. Is there any way to do this, or it is impossble?

```
let T = datatable(ColumnName:dynamic)
[
   dynamic({"OtherField": "Unknown","First": [{"Id": "","Second": [{"ConfidenceLevel": "Low","Count": 3}]},{"Id": "","Second":[{"ConfidenceLevel": "High","Count": 0}]}]}),
   dynamic({"OtherField": "Unknown","First": [{"Id": "","Second": [{"ConfidenceLevel": "Low","Count": 3}]},{"Id": "","Second":[{"ConfidenceLevel": "High","Count": 2}]}]})
];
let result = T
   // The following line works, but regex is not allowed during review.
   // | where tostring(ColumnName) matches regex '"ConfidenceLevel":"High","Count":[^0]'
   | where isnotnull(toscalar(
      // print s = '{"OtherField": "Unknown","First": [{"Id": "","Second": [{"ConfidenceLevel": "Low","Count": 3}]},{"Id": "","Second":[{"ConfidenceLevel": "High","Count": 0}]}]}'
      print s = tostring(ColumnName) // Error here: The name 'ColumnName' does not refer to any column, table, varible or function.
      | project obj0 = parse_json(s)
      | mv-expand obj1 = obj0.First
      | mv-expand obj2 = obj1.Second
      | where obj2.ConfidenceLevel == "High" and obj2.Count > 0)
      )
        ;
result
```

I tried and confirmed it was caused by toscalar function.

Expected result (The second row will be selected):

| ColumnName |
| --- |
| {"OtherField":"Unknown","First":[{"Id":"","Second":[{"ConfidenceLevel":"Low","Count":3}]},{"Id":"","Second":[{"ConfidenceLevel":"High","Count":2}]}]} |

Comment: Please provide a sample data + required results. If for some reason you are more focused on the error you get than on what you're trying to achieve, then please supply a minimal, reproducible code.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Answer (score 0):

1. 

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/toscalarfunction) is very clear about this:

> "The toscalar() function can't be applied on row-level (for-each-row scenario)."

2. 

Nested [mv-apply](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/mv-applyoperator), to deal with the nested arrays

```
let T = datatable(ColumnName:dynamic)
[
   dynamic({"OtherField": "Unknown","First": [{"Id": "","Second": [{"ConfidenceLevel": "Low","Count": 3}]},{"Id": "","Second":[{"ConfidenceLevel": "High","Count": 0}]}]}),
   dynamic({"OtherField": "Unknown","First": [{"Id": "","Second": [{"ConfidenceLevel": "Low","Count": 3}]},{"Id": "","Second":[{"ConfidenceLevel": "High","Count": 2}]}]})
];
T
|   mv-apply ColumnName.First on 
    (
        mv-apply ColumnName_First.Second on 
        (
            where   ColumnName_First_Second.ConfidenceLevel == "High" 
                and ColumnName_First_Second.Count > 0
        )
    )
|   project ColumnName
```

| ColumnName |
| --- |
| {"OtherField":"Unknown","First":[{"Id":"","Second":[{"ConfidenceLevel":"Low","Count":3}]},{"Id":"","Second":[{"ConfidenceLevel":"High","Count":2}]}]} |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA9WRwWrDMAyG7wa/g/ApgSyU7daRXQJlg7Id1p1KKFmste4cO2RuQ%20ny7lPiQrqQPcDkg21Zn/z/tkYHK0hA5o7Gu8YgtfpQmue8xLk8mbxURcjZmjMAuOyDs3hxO6wXCrUUcxBv5tPYxohILFT95Si1Poun/ohyr1hYI30yteZDSTQFLvGIuqtY2oaKUnswHXjXZm00AU%20zj2q7u4JnBGdtGP0LsbdeLGfZPWcrzr5Jc3m8yatKn2D4hLhXCdZA7woCP8F09aavjr2QARqBXTT0JkjzmN14Nh4ZgCS5OIDffbrI6a6/%205BdeIDZgIV%20GXrPVW33WLirBj9iIZD0lAIAAA==)