# How to query nested object in kusto?

Tags: kql

I have a kusto table with one of the columns as dynamic type with nested json. The dynamic object is two-dimensional array.

```
{
    "OtherField": "Unknown",
    "First": [
        {
            "Id": "",
            "Second": [
                {
                    "ConfidenceLevel": "Low",
                    "Count": 3
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Id": "",
            "Second": [
                {                   
                    "ConfidenceLevel": "High",
                    "Count": 2
                },
                {
                    "ConfidenceLevel": "Low",
                    "Count": 2
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Previously we use "tostring(ColumnName) has_cs '"Level":"High"'" to select rows if "Level" was matched, but now I want to select "Level == 'High' and Count > 0".
For this two-dimensional array, if one item was matched, then this row should be selected. How to implement nested object query in kusto?

I tried regex,

```
tostring(ColumnName) matches regex '"Level":"High","Count":[^0]'
```

but during review, regex was not allowed.

Then I tried "mv-expand" or "mv-apply", but it seems passing column name to toscalar function was not allowed.

[How to pass column name to toscalar function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74398898/how-to-pass-column-name-to-toscalar-function)

```
let T = datatable(ColumnName:dynamic)
[
   dynamic({"OtherField": "Unknown","First": [{"Id": "","Second": [{"ConfidenceLevel": "Low","Count": 3}]},{"Id": "","Second":[{"ConfidenceLevel": "High","Count": 0}]}]}),
   dynamic({"OtherField": "Unknown","First": [{"Id": "","Second": [{"ConfidenceLevel": "Low","Count": 3}]},{"Id": "","Second":[{"ConfidenceLevel": "High","Count": 2}]}]})
];
let result = T
   // The following line works, but regex is not allowed during review.
   // | where tostring(ColumnName) matches regex '"ConfidenceLevel":"High","Count":[^0]'
   | where isnotnull(toscalar(
      // print s = '{"OtherField": "Unknown","First": [{"Id": "","Second": [{"ConfidenceLevel": "Low","Count": 3}]},{"Id": "","Second":[{"ConfidenceLevel": "High","Count": 0}]}]}'
      print s = tostring(ColumnName) // Error here: The name 'ColumnName' does not refer to any column, table, varible or function.
      | project obj0 = parse_json(s)
      | mv-expand obj1 = obj0.First
      | mv-expand obj2 = obj1.Second
      | where obj2.ConfidenceLevel == "High" and obj2.Count > 0)
      )
        ;
result
```

I tried to use mv-expand function but got an error "The name 'ColumnName' does not refer to any column, table, varible or function."

Expected result (The second row will be selected):

ColumnName

{"OtherField":"Unknown","First":[{"Id":"","Second":[{"ConfidenceLevel":"Low","Count":3}]},{"Id":"","Second":[{"ConfidenceLevel":"High","Count":2}]}]}

Comment: Please add the required results,  in a tabular format

Answer (score 0):

Nested [mv-apply](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/mv-applyoperator), to deal with the nested arrays

```
let T = datatable(ColumnName:dynamic)
[
   dynamic({"OtherField": "Unknown","First": [{"Id": "","Second": [{"ConfidenceLevel": "Low","Count": 3}]},{"Id": "","Second":[{"ConfidenceLevel": "High","Count": 0}]}]}),
   dynamic({"OtherField": "Unknown","First": [{"Id": "","Second": [{"ConfidenceLevel": "Low","Count": 3}]},{"Id": "","Second":[{"ConfidenceLevel": "High","Count": 2}]}]})
];
T
|   mv-apply ColumnName.First on 
    (
        mv-apply ColumnName_First.Second on 
        (
            where   ColumnName_First_Second.ConfidenceLevel == "High" 
                and ColumnName_First_Second.Count > 0
        )
    )
|   project ColumnName
```

| ColumnName |
| --- |
| {"OtherField":"Unknown","First":[{"Id":"","Second":[{"ConfidenceLevel":"Low","Count":3}]},{"Id":"","Second":[{"ConfidenceLevel":"High","Count":2}]}]} |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA9WRwWrDMAyG7wa/g/ApgSyU7daRXQJlg7Id1p1KKFmste4cO2RuQ%20ny7lPiQrqQPcDkg21Zn/z/tkYHK0hA5o7Gu8YgtfpQmue8xLk8mbxURcjZmjMAuOyDs3hxO6wXCrUUcxBv5tPYxohILFT95Si1Poun/ohyr1hYI30yteZDSTQFLvGIuqtY2oaKUnswHXjXZm00AU%20zj2q7u4JnBGdtGP0LsbdeLGfZPWcrzr5Jc3m8yatKn2D4hLhXCdZA7woCP8F09aavjr2QARqBXTT0JkjzmN14Nh4ZgCS5OIDffbrI6a6/%205BdeIDZgIV%20GXrPVW33WLirBj9iIZD0lAIAAA==)

Comment: Thanks for your response, but current implement is we have a boolean expressions "A and B and C and D ...", A, B, C and D are all boolean types, is there a way to translate it into boolean types and place it in the old position? And that is the reason why I use toscalar, to translate result into boolean.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand this comment. This query uses the boolean expressions you provided  ("I want to select "Level == 'High' and Count > 0"") and returns the desired result.  If  for some reason you think this answer does not meet your question criteria, then please provide a new/extended sample data (+ required results) that will demonstrate your point.

Comment: This result is correct. The boolean condition is A and B and C and D, and in the previous B is "tostring(ColumnName) has_cs '"Level":"High"'",  but this query condition will cause a bug so I use regex to replace it, but regex is not allowed during review.

Comment: mv-expand or mv-apply is ok, but I found it is wrong to pass ColumnName to "toscalar" function. So is there a way to implement nested object query and keep the old coding logical not changed, that is to say, A and "fixed code" and C and D.

Comment: Buddy, I'm really trying to assist you here, but you don't make my life easier. I have no idea what is "A and B and C and D" nor why you claim that "this query condition will cause a bug".  please provide a new/extended sample data (+ required results) that will demonstrate your point.

Comment: LOL, sorry for my expression, previous condition is where CreationTime >= datetime(2020-09-11 00:00:00Z) and tostring(ColumnName) has_cs '\"ConfidenceLevel\":\"High\"' and Operation == "XXX" and CreationTime <= datetime(2022-09-11 00:00:00Z) . So B is “tostring(ColumnName) has_cs '\"ConfidenceLevel\":\"High\"' ” here, this expression result is boolean, but “tostring(ColumnName) has_cs '\"ConfidenceLevel\":\"High\"' is wrong, because it only takes ConfidenceLevel into consideration, if count is 0, the column will be wrongly selected.

Comment: So, I will fix this bug, replace “tostring(ColumnName) has_cs '\"ConfidenceLevel\":\"High\"' to a new query condition, firstly, I replace it with "tostring(ColumnName) matches regex '"ConfidenceLevel":"High","Count":[^0]'", but regex is not allowed during review. So I tried to use mv-expand, but mv-expand result is  table? or other type, so I convert it into scalar, but passing ColumnName to toscalar function is not allowed. Thanks very much for your patience.

Comment: Why do you claim that "this query condition will cause a bug" when you can clearly see that both conditions are covered  (`where ColumnName_First_Second.ConfidenceLevel == "High" and ColumnName_First_Second.Count > 0`)? Once again - If you think that I'm meesing something, please provide a new/extended sample data (+ required results) that will demonstrate your point.

Comment: Sorry, some misunderstanding here, "this query condition will cause a bug" means old query, `tostring(ColumnName) has_cs '\"ConfidenceLevel\":\"High\"`. This query `where ColumnName_First_Second.ConfidenceLevel == "High" and ColumnName_First_Second.Count > 0` is correct. Currently I am wondering if there is a way to convert `mv-expand` result into boolean.

Comment: Why are we talking about `mv-expand` if I'm not using it in my solution? I'm asking once again - please provide a new/extended sample data (+ required results) that will demonstrate your point.

Comment: `let T = datatable(ColumnName:dynamic)
[
   dynamic({"OtherField": "Unknown","First": [{"Id": "","Second": [{"ConfidenceLevel": "Low","Count": 3}]},{"Id": "","Second":[{"ConfidenceLevel": "High","Count": 0}]}]}),
   dynamic({"OtherField": "Unknown","First": [{"Id": "","Second": [{"ConfidenceLevel": "Low","Count": 3}]},{"Id": "","Second":[{"ConfidenceLevel": "High","Count": 2}]}]})
];`